# MySQL Conditional Syntax Based On SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have this table, named reward :

```
+----+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id | product_id | sell_what | get_what | valid_until |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 1  | 1001       | 10        | 10000    | 15 nov 2015 |
| 2  | 1002       | 7         | 12000    | 31 dec 2015 |
| 3  | 1003       | 12        | 100000   | 31 dec 2015 |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

and, I have this table, named user_earned :

```
+----+---------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| id | user_id | product_id | sell_what | transaction_date |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | 609     | 1003       | 1         | 2 Nov 2015       |
| 2  | 220     | 1001       | 12        | 3 Nov 2015       |
| 3  | 609     | 1003       | 1         | 20 Nov 2015      |
| 4  | 910     | 1001       | 2         | 21 Nov 2015      |
| 5  | 910     | 1001       | 3         | 21 Nov 2015      |
| 6  | 910     | 1001       | 8         | 22 Nov 2015      |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I also have this query to sum `sell_what` number based on `user_id` :

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, 
SUM(sell_what) AS sold, 
MAX(transaction_date) AS transaction_date
FROM user_earned 
GROUP BY user_id, product_id
```

and here's the result :

```
+---------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| user_id | product_id | sold      | transaction_date |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| 220     | 1001       | 12        | 3 Nov 2015       |
| 609     | 1003       | 2         | 20 Nov 2015      |
| 910     | 1001       | 13        | 22 Nov 2015      |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

now, the problem is... how to join that result with table reward so that I got table like this :

```
+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------+
| user_id | product_id | sold      | remaining_balance |
+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------+
| 220     | 1001       | 12        | 2                 |
+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

user 609 is not visible because he only has 2 products sold, while minimum reward of product 1003 is 12.

user 910 is not visible because his latest transaction_date of product 1001 is 22 Nov 2015, while the reward only valid until 15 Nov 2015.

how to apply this conditional into one SQL syntax? thank you.

Comment: 1. Store dates as dates 2. Tell us about earned_incentive

Comment: ok, I think I got what you want...

Comment: BTW : you got an error in your query : `FROM earned_incentive` but you use `user_earned` just above for the table name...

Comment: @Blag : you're right... edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this kind of request ?

```
select * ,
    (t.sold - r.sell_what) as remaining_balance
from reward as r
inner join (
    SELECT user_id, product_id, 
    SUM(sell_what) AS sold, 
    MAX(transaction_date) AS transaction_date
    FROM earned_incentive 
    GROUP BY user_id, product_id
    ) as t
    on r.product_id = t.product_id
WHERE 
    r.sell_what <= t.sold
    and t.transaction_date <= r.valid_until
```

Check the [SQL Fiddle[image: sqlfiddle]